# Timeout Exception While calling JsonpRequestBuilder.requestObject()

Tags: json, gwt

i am having timeout exception while calling `JsonpRequestBuilder` request.

I am also refer [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404359/gwt-jsonprequestbuilder-timeout-issue) but i am getting timeout exception every time.

My entry point class is

```
package com.dips.restcalls.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.jsonp.client.JsonpRequestBuilder;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public class RequestClass implements EntryPoint {


        @Override
        public void onModuleLoad() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            private static final String JSON_URL = "http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.test.echo&format=json&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXX";

            JsonpRequestBuilder builder = new JsonpRequestBuilder();
            builder.setTimeout(1000);
            builder.setCallbackParam("jsonCallback");
            builder.requestObject(JSON_URL, new AsyncCallback<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("Fails...."+ caught);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(T result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("Sucess...");
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

you can get flickr json url from [Here](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html)

My JavaScriptObject class is

```
package com.dips.restcalls.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;

public class T extends JavaScriptObject {

    public T() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

In Firebug i am getting json response but, in console i am getting Timeout Exception every time.
Please, Help me.

Comment: The Flickr documentation talks about a `jsoncallback` parameter whereas you are using `jsonCallback` (uppercase C). Have you tried with the lower-case one? Which function (function name) is being called by the script returned by Flickr?